# How do I implement two <selects with <options> in same php page

Tags: php, html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> <b> Select the colors you want </b> </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM action="colortables.php" method='post'>
<p>Pick one or more of the colors: </p><br/>
<select name='bcolors[]' size=8 multiple>
<?php
  $pickcolors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'white' 'purple');
  foreach ($pickcolors as $colors) {
    printf("<option value='%s'>%s", $colors, $colors);
  }
?>
</select>
<select name='tcolors[]' size=8 multiple>
<?php
  $pickcolors2 = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'white', 'purple');
   foreach ($pickcolors2 as $colors) {
     printf("<option value='%s'>%s", $colors, $colors);
   }
?>
</select>
<p><input type='submit' value='pick'></p>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

So I am still relatively new to HTML so go easy on me, I want the code above to put two simple boxes with 8 color options in each box that you can pic to submit a multiplication table-esque of the color and text combinations. For some reason though this code no matter what I pick for text colors it says that I haven't picked any. any help would be great

EDIT: tcolors is text colors and bcolors is background colors

Comment: $pickcolors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'white' 'purple'); missing -> "," after "white"

Comment: have u try this print_r($_POST); on colortables.php page??

Answer (score 0):

When you used `printf()` you didnt close the `<option>` tag. Also fix the `,` in the array as @Ashish spotted out.

```
<select name='bcolors[]' size=8 multiple>
<?php
   $pickcolors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'white', 'purple');
   foreach ($pickcolors as $colors) {
      echo "<option value='$colors'>$colors</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

Replace the second `select` also like the one i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use same array for both the select boxes.

you may do like

```
<select name='bcolors[]' size=8 multiple>
<?php
  $pickcolors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'white','purple');
  foreach ($pickcolors as $colors) {
    echo "<option value='".$colors."'>".$colors."</option>";
  }
?>
</select>

<!-- second select box with same array -->
<select name='tcolors[]' size=8 multiple>
<?php
  foreach ($pickcolors as $colors) {
    echo "<option value='".$colors."'>".$colors."</option>";
  }
?> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma (,) between `'white' and 'purple'` in first array

and did not close option in loop

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> <b> Select the colors you want </b> </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM action="colortables.php" method='post'>
<p>Pick one or more of the colors: </p><br/>
<select name='bcolors[]' size=8 multiple>
<?php
  $pickcolors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'white', 'purple');
  foreach ($pickcolors as $colors) {
    printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $colors, $colors);
  }
?>
</select>
<select name='tcolors[]' size=8 multiple>
<?php
  $pickcolors2 = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'white', 'purple');
   foreach ($pickcolors2 as $colors) {
     printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $colors, $colors);
   }
?>
</select>
<p><input type='submit' value='pick'></p>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select name='bcolors[]' size=8 multiple>
    <?php
      $pickcolors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'white', 'purple');
      foreach ($pickcolors as $key1=>$value1) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value1;?>"><?php echo $value1;?></option>
     <?php }
    ?>
    </select>
    <select name='tcolors[]' size=8 multiple>
    <?php
      $pickcolors2 = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black', 'white', 'purple');
       foreach ($pickcolors2 as $keys=>$values) {?>

     <option value="<?php echo $$values;?>"><?php echo $values;?></option>

    <?php   }
    ?>
    </select>

<inpu type="submit" name="submit" value="pick">
```